# JS doesn't load in Liferay theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, liferay

I'm including datatables.js to my Liferay theme so it can be used for all the portlets in that theme. I have included it in the

> portal_normal.vm

just above te end og the body tag like this

```
<script src="$theme_dir/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="$theme_dir/js/jquery-ui.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="$theme_dir/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="$theme_dir/js/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<script src="$theme_dir/js/clndr.js"></script>
<script src="$theme_dir/js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="$theme_dir/js/es.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="$theme_dir/js/fullcalendar.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="$theme_dir/js/bootstrap-year-calendar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="$theme_dir/js/bootstrap-year-calendar.es.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="$theme_dir/js/form-solicitud.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="$theme_dir/js/filterable.pack.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="$theme_dir/js/datatables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

The problem is that the datatable.js seems to load correctly, but when I refresh the page with F5 it doesn't load the js.

I've tried to load the js also in the

> portal_pop_up.vm

but it doesn't work at all.

Comment: I'm using Chrome as a browser, if I used Fire Fox it works properly

Comment: If it works in FF I would guess that the error is _in_ the JS file and has nothing to do with the inclusion itself.